# How to find a line that stabs the maximum possible number of segments?

Tags: geometry, computer-science, discrete-geometry

Suppose we are given $N$ arbitrary different angle segments in the plane that are disjoint, and we want to find a line that stabs the maximal number of segments. How to do this? I thought about quad trees but it doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

> Edelsbrunner, Herbert, Hermann A. Maurer, Franco P. Preparata, Arnold L. Rosenberg, Emo Welzl, and Derick Wood. "Stabbing line segments." *BIT Numerical Mathematics* 22, no. 3 (1982): 274-281.
>   ([PDF download](http://www.rendezvouswithdestiny.net/index_files/StabbingLineSegments.pdf).)

They dualize line segments to double wedges and use that representation for
their algorithms.

---

[image: DoubleWedges]

---